# Is there any way to reorganize node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

There is big and deep node_modules directory. And there are many sub-folders with the same modules that are located in different subdirectories. Sometimes the same versions of the modules, there are sometimes differences in minor versions.

Is there a tool for reorganization of node_modules to remove duplicates, put them in the root directory and somehow still a bunch of modules to optimize this?

Comment: Just curious: have you found that some of the modules are duplicates including the version?  I wonder how many modules you have--some stats would be interesting.

Comment: Have you looked at `npm dedupe`? https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-dedupe.html

Comment: @john-zwinck `npm list | wc-l` showed about 3000 modules

Comment: You have 3000 modules?  Are these dependencies for a single project, or multiple projects, or your entire system?  I wonder how many dupes there are, too.

Comment: Given that `node_modules/` is in .gitignore and that node caches a module once it's been loaded i.e. it doesn't reload it each time some other module needs it as a dependency, is there a benefit in reorganizing other than saving disk space?

Comment: No there is no way of optimizing this, why? because whenever a user installs a package from npm repository, npm queries the npm server for all available information, if something returns `non modified` it loads the package from `npm-cache` if not retrieves, and stores again at npm-cache directory so when you need it again it will be there. `node_modules` is directory of modules your project requires to run. then each module in that directory has its own dependecies, you really can't achieve optimization with this..

Comment: Did my answer help you out Serg?

Comment: Alex, yeah, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NPM hierarchy is actually fairly complex and they've done a lot of work to optimize it. The most you're losing here is a little disk space. If you really need to prune the package structure for your app then you can take a look at [npm dedupe](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-dedupe.html) which is built right into npm and does exactly what you're asking for (consolidates duplicates as much as possible).

I know a lot of people are against checking in node_modules directory but in production applications we've found that checking in node_modules makes it so much easier to pin down fatal changes in our application. Sure you usually know that your application broke after the last `npm update` but if your app is rather large like ours is then that simply isn't granular enough to solve problems quickly and efficiently. So in large production applications (i.e. not libraries being published to NPM) I use `npm dedupe` to simplify the package structure before checking them in.

If you're writing code that others will consume (via NPM or otherwise) then checking in node_modules isn't the best idea and you should avoid doing so by adding node_modules to your version control system's ignore list. You should also make sure you're dependencies in `package.json` are specific version numbers with as few ranges as possible (please don't put asterisks in place of the version numbers in your production apps :/).

If you follow those basic patterns then you can just forget about the node_modules directory and let npm take care of you.